# Spherical cap is the only compact constant mean curvature surface bounded by a circle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I would like to see that the only compact rotationally invariant constant mean curvature surfaces with boundary a planar circle, are either a planar disk or a spherical cap. 
This is stated in the proof of corollary 4.1.3 in the book "Constant mean curvature surfaces with boundary" by Rafael Lopez. 
I have thought about this for some time but could not come up with any answers. So I hoped one of you could suggest a good reference or explain the idea to me for proving this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you are restricting to axisymmetric surfaces, this seems like a straight-forward 1d calculus problem. Can you elaborate on what you tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: P.S. Are there non-axisymmetric compact surfaces of constant mean curvature whose boundary is the circle?

Comment: @YoavKallus, not compact, Riemann made a minimal surface of a sort of staircase shape, in every parallel plane the intersection with the surface is either a circle or a line.

Comment: @Yoav 
Its not entirely trivial.  The symmetries reduce this to second order ODE, but its not entirely obvious that the only solutions to this corresponding to compact surfaces are spherical caps (for instance the Delaunay surfaces are non-compact solutions but can self-intersect).  The insight that simplifies things is that the "flux" of CMC surfaces corresponds to an first integral of the ODE and being a closed surface implies that this integral is identically zero.  This is then a simple calculus exercise.

Comment: Tom, your surfaces, dropping the compactness condition, are solutions of a second order ODE. Most of them need two circle boundaries to end up compact, for example an ordinary circular cylinder cut off at two circular ends. "In 1841 Delaunay proved that the only surfaces of revolution with constant mean curvature were the surfaces obtained by rotating the roulettes of the conics. These are the plane, cylinder, sphere, the catenoid, the unduloid and nodoid"

Comment: @Yoav A further remark, if the surface is embedded, then Alexandrov's moving planes method implies it is rotationally symmetric and hence a spherical cap.  Somewhat surprisingly, in the non-minimal case this is, if I remember correctly, an open question for immersed surfaces (its vacuously trivial in the minimal case by the convex hull property).

Comment: It is classical to prove that there is only a one parameter family of CMC of revolution: the delaunay surface's. But only one closes up... the sphere.

Comment: @Rbega, Will Jagy, Thank you for your useful comments, I will surely look into these Delaunay surfaces. If we 'assume' this classification then the result follows 'almost trivially'.